# Сложить datetime.time() и минуты

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

Как сложить в python `datetime.time()` и `datetime.timedelta(minutes = minute)` ?

Answer (score 4):

Складывайте c `timedelta` тип `datetime`:

```
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.now()
print(dt)
# 2020-06-19 20:27:27.566957

print(dt + datetime.timedelta(minutes=10))
# 2020-06-19 20:37:27.566957
```